# ¿En breve o en breves momentos?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Un presentador de televisión anunciando la casi inmediata aparición de alguna persona. Cual es modo correcto de anunciarlo:
"En breve estaremos con ..."
"En breves momentos estaremos con ..."
"En breves instantes estaremos con ..."
"En un instante estaremos con ..."
"En unos instantes estaremos con ..."

A mi me gusta más ***en breve*** a secas, y esa opción supongo que sea correcta, pero ... ¿Las otras son correctas? ¿Se puede decir que alguna es óptima sobre las demás?

Comment: Todo depende del lugar, país, región. Lo más importante es enfocarse en la idea y que se entienda.
Hoy, ninguna lengua es pura, la internet ha traído la universalidad, si algo se entiende, no hay necesidad de tanto análisis. La lengua es algo vivo, más aún el español, que surge del corazón.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La Fundéu [aclara al respecto](http://www.fundeu.es/consultas-E-en-breves-momentos-332.html) que "en breves momentos" es un anglicismo y que se desaconseja su uso en favor de "en breve".

> Del cruce de «en breve» y el anglicismo mencionado ['en una hora' en lugar de 'dentro de una hora'] surge el híbrido
>   «en breves momentos» con el significado de 'dentro de unos momentos',
>   'en breve', 'dentro de poco', 'muy pronto'.
>
> Recomendamos evitar «en breves momentos» y utilizar otra fórmula más
>   adecuada [...]

Comment: Gracias es de lo que quería asegurarme.

Answer (score 0):

**Instante**: Porción brevísima de tiempo. (RAE)

Cómo te suena:

> En breves instantes llegaremos a casa

Algo así:

> En brevísimas porciones de tiempo llegaremos a casa.

Suena fatal y además hay redundancia pues instante ya es breve.

Instante tiene plural, pero hay que utilizarlo bien:

> "Por instantes se escuchaba un ruido raro".

No se trata de: "Si me entienden está bien dicho".

Con "Momento" pasa casi lo mismo.

Answer (score -1):

En mi opinión, no hay mucho que decir. Todas las opciones son exactamente igual de correctas, puedes escoger la que más te agrade.

Comment: Pero ... instantes ¿es correcto? A mi me suena raro cada vez que lo escucho. Por ejemplo se usa indistintamente en un instante y en unos instantes. ¿Singular o plural? ¿Los dos son válidos?  No sucede lo mismo con momento, la cual de plano me parece desacertado usarlo en plural. Por ejemplo me parece bien decir en un momento, pero en unos momentos me parece fatal. Sin embargo en el uso de instante en plural no me aseguro del todo que decir en unos instantes esté mal usado.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero: Instante, instantes, momento y momentos son todos correctos en este contexto. No existe ninguna regla, explicación o razón para usar uno u otro. Si los usos en plural no te gustan, pues no los uses, pero si alguien más los utiliza pues recuerda que no esta hablando incorrectamente.

Comment: Pues parece que si habla incorrectamente. Al menos introduce formas de hablar no propias de  nuestro idioma. De plano me voy asegurando mas cada vez mirando la respuesta de  @JoulSauron de que las formas en plural son totalmente incorrectas. Por demás me parece que en el lenguaje hablado, en la televisión más, el lenguaje debiera ser lo más directo posible.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero: nada puede hacerse si tu consulta no es realmente por una duda sino para que te confirmen tu opinión. Pero quiero hacerte notar que nadie te la ha confirmado: la Fundéu cuidadosamente evita decir que la expresión sea _incorrecta_. Tan sólo dice que se debe a la influencia del inglés y que ellos, porque cultivan un estilo que desprecia las influencias del inglés, lo desaconsejan. La _corrección_ nunca es mencionada, porque la expresión es correcta.

Comment: Si puede hacerse, si hago la pregunta es porque me suena mal. Si alguien me confirma lo contrario (que no ha sido el caso) mi opinión cambiaría. En cuanto a que desprecien las influencias del inglés creo que no es lo más apropiado, quizás fomenten un español castizo, con las justas influencias. Pero de ahí a despreciar creo que es exagerado, y si fuera asi borraré a la Fundéu de mis favoritos.

Comment: Reconozco a su favor que alguna de las formas pueden ser correctas, sin embargo para un medio como la televisión que es el contexto en que me refería el lenguaje debiera ser directo y anunciar en breve, a secas parece ser la expresión óptima. Y no estaba seguro antes de hacer la pregunta pero mirando por este medio y otros me he convencido.